# Как сделать гистограмму? (golang)

Tags: golang

Нужно сделать гистограмму используя golang. Для этого использую библиотеку `gonum.org/v1/plot` Вот мой код:

```
func (l Lab1) createHistigram(p []float64, fileName, histogramName string) {
    var values plotter.Values
    values = append(values, p...)
    pl, err := plot.New()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    pl.Title.Text = histogramName
    hist, err := plotter.NewHist(values, 10)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    pl.Add(hist)
    if err := pl.Save(5*vg.Inch, 5*vg.Inch, fileName); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

В `p` содержится такой срез: `[0.09 0.11 0.1 0.14 0.11 0.11 0.07 0.08 0.07 0.12]`.
В срезе `p` будет постоянно лежать 10 элементов. И хотелось бы, чтоб ось X была подписана `[0 0.1 0.2 ... 0.9 1.0]` постоянно. А ось Y отображала значения среза `p`. Но моя гистограмма выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос заменой `hist, err := plotter.NewHist(values, 10)` на `hist, err := plotter.NewBarChart(values, 10)`